# dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_LocalizationsScope>

Tags: flutter, dart

I translating in Text widgets(check `List<Map<String, Object>> screens`).
To translate using intl plugin.
Shows this error:
[image]

My code:

```
class TabScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabScreenState createState() => _TabScreenState();
}

class _TabScreenState extends State<TabScreen> {
  List<Map<String, Object>> screens;
  @override
  initState() {
    screens = [
      {
        "screen": DistanceScreen(),
        "title": Text(S.of(context).DistanceScreenTranslate) 
      },
      {"screen": TemperatureScreen(), "title": Text("Temperature Convertor")},
      {"screen": CurrencyScreen(), "title": Text("Currency Convertor")},
      {"screen": TimeScreen(), "title": Text("Time Convertor")},
      {"screen": NumberScreen(), "title": Text("Binary Convertor")},
    ];
    getCurrentExchangeRates();
    super.initState();
  }

  var selectedPageIndex = 0;
  void selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/icons/double-arrow.png',
            height: 5,
            width: 5,
          ),
        ),
        title: screens[selectedPageIndex]["title"],
```

Help me please!

Comment: RedScreensOfDeath are not useful.  If anything, include the output in your debug console that shows at least a few levels of the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text(S.of(context).DistanceScreenTranslate)` : you do not have access to `BuildContext` in `initState` because it is yet to be created.
Consider using same statements inside `didChangeDependecies` method. It is safe option to access `BuildContext` before build method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async { $place your state to init here });
```

It could be async or not.

make sure to `listen: false` if using provider.